# Association bonus not awarded when joining new site, plus profile not updated

Tags: support, bug, linked-accounts, association-bonus

I just joined [pets.stackexchange.com](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/11922/user11922?tab=profile)

While joining [Error page appeared](https://pets.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/openidconfirm) (error page does not specify any details but URL indicates openid error?)

I noticed I did not receive association bonus and also my account name is user11922 instead of [Piro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651107/piro)

Comment: [delete](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) and rejoin (recreate your account on that site).

Comment: @JohnMiliter that works. Did not see such suggestion on other `Association bonus not awarded` questions. What now, should I add tag [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: You can't Mark as status completed. That you needed to do so feels like a bug anyway

Comment: The association bonus can take time to be awarded too, it got 3 days on one site I joined in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed [@JohnMiliter's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308984/association-bonus-not-awarded-when-joining-new-site-plus-profile-not-updated#comment1006972_308984), deleted and joined again. And it is working as intended.